# Issue with enable_if and multiple conditions

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, enable-if

I tried to implement a function which converts a generic type to a string. Integral types need to be converted using `std::to_string()`, strings and chars using `std::string()` and vectors, element by element, to a string using one of the other methods (depending on their content).

This is what I have:

```
//Arithmetic types    

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, std::string>::type convertToString(const T& t){
    return std::to_string(t);
}

//Other types using string ctor

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_arithmetic<T>>::type,
        std::__not_<std::is_same<T, <T,
       std::vector<typename T::value_type, typename T::allocator_type>>::value
       >>>::value, std::string>::type convertToString(const T& t){
    return std::string(t);
}

//Vectors

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::vector<typename T::value_type, 
   typename T::allocator_type>>::value, std::string>::type convertToString(const T& t){
    std::string str;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < t.size(); i++){
        str += convertToString(t[i]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

The problem is that the 2nd function does not compile. How can I design the 2nd function so that it does compile (and work) and does not create ambiguity issues?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Oktalist's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41534797/2069064) answer explains why your type trait doesn't compile. Also, you shouldn't use `__and_` and `__not_`. Those are reserved and could easily change in the next compiler version. It's easy enough to implement your own version of those traits (e.g. see the possible implementation of [`conjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction)).

I would suggest an entirely different approach. We can use `choice<>` to make overloading these cases far simpler:

```
template <int I> struct choice : choice<I+1> { };
template <> struct choice<10> { };
```

Via:

```
// arithmetic version
template <class T>
auto convertToStringHelper(T const& t, choice<0> )
    -> decltype(std::to_string(t))
{
    return std::to_string(t);
}

// non-arithmetic version
template <class T>
auto convertToStringHelper(T const& t, choice<1> )
    -> decltype(std::string(t))
{
    return std::string(t);
}

// vector version
template <class T, class A>
std::string convertToStringHelper(std::vector<T,A> const& v, choice<2> )
{
    // implementation here
}

template <class T>
std::string convertToString(T const& t) {
    return convertToStringHelper(t, choice<0>{});
}
```

This is nice because you get all the SFINAE without any of the `enable_if` cruft.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution :) I don't like the enable_if syntax very much as is makes code hard to read.

Comment: That's a really good solution; took me a while to figure out how it works, until I realised that it would just slice the `choice<0>` until it reached a matching function.  I do believe it has one issue, though: According to the question, he wants `char`s to be processed by the `choice<1>` version, not the `choice<0>` version ([which it currently calls](http://ideone.com/O3N4xB)).

Comment: @JustinTime `char` is arithmetic, so this matches the OP's ordering. Easy to flip though.

Comment: @Barry True.  Just figured I'd point it out so he could see it now, instead of having to search through his project for a potential bug later.

Comment: @Barry Can someone please explain how this works?

Answer (score 5):

One possible way is to add *is_vector* trait (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512678/check-at-compile-time-is-a-template-type-a-vector) for more details):

```
template<typename T> struct is_vector : public std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename A>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, A>> : public std::true_type {};
```

And then modify your *convertToString* function templates as follows:

```
// Arithmetic types

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, std::string>::type convertToString(const T& t) {
    return std::to_string(t);
}

// Other types using string ctor

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !is_vector<T>::value, std::string>::type convertToString(const T& t) {
    return std::string(t);
}

// Vectors

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && is_vector<T>::value, std::string>::type convertToString(const T& t) {
    std::string str;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < t.size(); i++){
        str += convertToString(t[i]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/M3oKkDMyD2fOXHMo)

Answer (score 3):

The template with errors marked:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_arithmetic<T>>::type,
//                                                                    ^^^^^^[1]
        std::__not_<std::is_same<T, <T,
//                                  ^^^[2]
       std::vector<typename T::value_type, typename T::allocator_type>>::value
//                                                                     ^^^^^^^[3]
       >>>::value, std::string>::type convertToString(const T& t){
//       ^[4]
    return std::string(t);
}
// [1] nested ::type not needed and ill-formed without typename keyword
// [2] <T, is garbage
// [3] nested ::value ill-formed because std::__not_ argument must be a type
// [4] too many closing angle brackets
```

The template with errors fixed:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_arithmetic<T>>,
        std::__not_<std::is_same<T,
       std::vector<typename T::value_type, typename T::allocator_type>>
       >>::value, std::string>::type convertToString(const T& t){
    return std::string(t);
}
```

Comment: Let's also not use implementation details of a particular standard library vendor.

Comment: I know, I wasn't sure if I can use && or ! because the standard library doesn't use it.

Comment: @T.C. Beyond the scope of the question (which I voted to close anyway) but feel free to edit it into this answer or provide your own.

Comment: @Overblade The source code of a standard library implementation is a *horrible* place to learn C++ from.

Comment: Haha, I know :)

Comment: @Overblade [You can use operators with templates & `std::enable_if`.](http://ideone.com/u8472X)